# container instance azure created based on docker image not accessible

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have created and container instance in azure and the docker container is running
actually, I can see in the logs that the spring boot app is started and connected to the mongo.
I have in the properties the public IP, the DNS, and FQDN,
I would like to access the internet using the FQDN; for example:

GET https://app.azurecontainer.io/api/v1/clients

but it does not respond anything
I'm doing something wrong, using postman is not working as well.
I don't have any idea how to access it.

Comment: SHare the complete infra if possible also have you checked your nsg configuration ?

Comment: My mistake, actually is working I was missing the port https://app.azurecontainer.io:xxxx/api/v1/clients

Answer (score 0):

Unable to get the respond information of the container instance.

You tried to add a port to solve this problem. I summarized it into an answer, hoping to help more forum users.

```
app.azurecontainer.io:{port}/api/v1/clients
```